# Creating custom library for Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, customization

My question is simple. Since Mysql is open source so, can we create an library file for mysql or modify existing lib file of mysql. for example, I want to changed the name of the "INNER JOIN" to "INSIDE JOIN".

Question 1 > Can we do this ?

Question 2 > If yes, what are the steps like find and edit a mysql lib file, compile and save it, restart the mysql service OR reference for the steps .. ?

Comment: Why in the *world* would you want to do this?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. Please don't do this. Ever.

Comment: So you want to customize your mySQL installation so that nothing you create will ever work on anything else, and you'll probably never be able to patch/update mySQL without *significant* overhead in time and effort? Sounds super.

Comment: Sorry for not asking exact question. I don't want to change SQL standards, "INNER JOIN" to "INSIDE JOIN" was just an example, i think i really hit on the nerve there :p. I just wanted to know about the implementation of the INNER JOIN so that i can try creating custom JOIN of my own and Why Mysql! its an open source. if we can do it in SQLite, that will be much easier.

Comment: Thank you all for such quick answers. I learn something new.

Comment: It's probably better to work within the constraints of MySQL or pick a different RDBMS that does what you want than to mangle MySQL to do what you want. Custom builds of important infrastructure software tend to become a gigantic liability.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend signing up for the next [SQL standard committee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL:2011) and submitting a change request. Then, when the SQL:2020 standard is put out, MySQL will implement this change for you and you will have exactly what you want.

Comment: Considering how mySQL doesn't have CTEs and other various SQL standards yet, this might take about 20 years..

Comment: Thanks tadman, i think i need to ask my question SQL standard committee.